# Left shift operator with Matrix3f

Tags: c++

I encountered a piece of code like this:

```
Eigen::Matrix3f rotationZ;
rotationZ << std::cos(angle), -std::sin(angle), 0, std::sin(angle), std::cos(angle), 0, 0, 0, 1;
```

It doesnt make any sense to me, why left shift with non integers values (sin, cos values) ? Why do they even use this operator ?

Comment: `<<` doesn't have to mean bitshift. in c++ streams, it means "insertion". here, its used as a builder

Comment: @vu1p3n0x meaning it just adds those values into the matrix ? Thank you

Comment: yes, it is documented [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html)